# Correct way to login users through API and session variables

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, session-variables

I have a ruby on rails app that simply serves as an API. Users must pass a valid key in with every request. Now I'm building a front end for the app using AngularJS. Angular takes input from users, and passes it into PHP files on the server that then make API calls and return data as JSON objects that are parsed and presented by Angular.

Now I want to make certain data from the api only available to logged in users. Here's the approach I want to take, and I just want to see if this is secure or if I should be doing something different:

1. User enters email/password in Angular app.
2. This is sent as a post request to a PHP file.
3. The PHP file posts this email/password to the rails-based api.
4. Rails does the authentication. If these are valid user credentials, it returns the user's api key, if not, it sends a failure message.
5. PHP file saves the api key to the user's session variable.
6. This session variable is used to make future api calls, so the API will determine whether the user can access certain data or not.

I'm still in the planning phases, so I know I left out a lot of error handling, but is this a viable basic model for user auth through an API? If not, what would be better?

Comment: Sounds perfectly fine to me, especially when acting on behalf of a user to the third party.

Comment: I hope when you said "api key" you really meant "random token".

Comment: @aet yep, that's exactly what it is. At this point it isn't even presented to the user anywhere in the app.